# How do I get clipping masks to snap to grid in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've searched and can't seem to find anyone on the internet who has actually solved this problem.

I've been dealing with this in over eight versions of illustrator over eight years, four computers, and three operating systems, and was wondering if anyone here has a solution.

I have snap to grid on as well as the grid displayed, but upon creating a clipping mask I cannot snap to grid. I can reproduce this in different documents, with different image sizes, different images, and different grid sizes.

Cutting and pasting doesn't work as well as dragging and dropping.

I think adobe is just really awful at making grids as I've encountered probably sixty problems with them over the years and they're just buggy, but this particular one has been driving me crazy for a while. Help appreciated.

[image: grid snap fail]

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution, if feasible, draw the clipping mask shape first and snap it to the grid, then make the clipping mask.

AI does indeed have considerable trouble snapping a non-grid uniform clipping mask after it's been created. - meaning.. if the mask shape doesn't conform to grid divisions.. AI gets confused.

Mask shape not conforming to grid divisions... **can't** get it to snap correctly.

[image]

.. as opposed to drawing a proper grid-division shape *first*, then creating the clipping mask.... which *does* correctly snap....

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had created the shape on grid before hand, and changed the picture to be on grid with one dimension (but could not for the other without distortion)

Comment: It shouldn't matter if what's *inside* the clipping mask conforms to the grid or not. There *may* be snapping to the mask contents as well as napping to the mask shape. If the edges of the two are close to each other, that can make snapping a more delicate procedure. - but you should still see snapping to the mask shape.